# WPF/XAML: Shortcut to a user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, label, keyboard-shortcuts

I have created a UserControl named ContactPerson. It contains a persons name, phone number etc.

This usercontrol does not have a headline (ie. a label such as "_Contact Person") because I use this usercontrol in different situations.

However in one situation, I do have such a label, which means my code look somewhat like this:

```
<Label Content="_Contact Person" 
       Target="{Binding ElementName=_contactView}" />


<View1:contactView x:Name="_contactView" 
                   DataContext="{Binding SupplierContact}"/>
```

I want - to set keyboard focus to the name-textbox inside the ContactPersonUserControl but it seems to be a difficult task (it is private after alle).

I do not want to move the label inside the usercontrol, which I guess would in fact be the most simple solution. It seems to me that XAML should provide a solution to this scenario.

How to do this in a simple and elegant way?

Thx

(I have a few of these controls, so I'll need to use the same solution several times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether i understand your scenario correctly, But if you want to set focus to ui control from view model, then you may need to create an attached property.

**Attached Property:**

```
 public static class ControlFocusExtension
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(ControlFocusExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

        public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
        }



        private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject pDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uie = (UIElement)pDependencyObject;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                uie.Focus(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

**User control XAML:**

Now in your View (in XAML) you can bind this property to your ViewModel:

```
<TextBox local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsNameFocused}" />
```

You can change the value of **IsNameFocused** from your view model if needed.

Alternatively if you don't want to bind this then you can use it as -

```
<TextBox local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set focusvisualstyle property null for those you dont want to set focus  like this

example   `<Label FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">`

and for  textbox focus `<TextBox Focusable="True"/>`